# Method Caller and Callee, circular class level method invocations

Tags: java, oop, interface, polymorphism, higher-order-functions

What are the problems with doing method caller and Callee of two different classes doing circular class level different method calls. You pass "this" reference, as a parameter to some other class instance method and the Callee doing further method invitation on caller which is passed as parameter.

One reason for doing that, In a factory class,  Different implementations needs different kinds of data, so you put the data that is needed as multiple contracts/interface methods and have your caller implement them. If you have just one class it is easier to implement encapsulation, But **different classes require different sets of data**.

Following is simple example of such, Here  StudentService calls MathClassScorer's topscorer method which in turn calls StudentService's  getStudentList method. In a complex scenario, you might be calling multiple methods of parent caller.

```
public interface IStudentData { 
    public List<Student> getStudentList();
}

public class StudentService implements IStudentData {
       private List<Student> studentList;

       public String getTop() {
            // Factory returns MathClassScorer
            IScore scorer = ClassScorerFactory.get();
            return scorer.topscorer(someOtherData, this);
       }

       @Override
       public getStudentList() {
          // do something and return studentList;
          return studentList;
       }

}

// IScore contains topscorer method
public class MathClassScorer implements IScore {

     @Override
     public String topscorer(Map someOtherData, IStudentData data) {
         List<Student> studentList = data.getStudentList();
         //do something before and after
         return SOMETHING_AFTER
     }
}
```

The Question is, Is there problem in the above approach ?

Comment: There are no problems with doing that.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Question is, Is there any issue with the approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the whole topic of OO is a bit controversial I'm afraid. But in my opinion the problems with the above code start with the naming of your classes. `IStudentData` is not an object. Holding some data is not a *responsibility*, and objects need responsibilities.

Then the design requires that the `IScore` objects know about the internal data content of the `IStudentData`, disregarding the object completely. The code also suggests that the `IScore` needs to know about the internal workings of `Student` too.

A good OO design is where objects actually have responsibilities, and their data is visible as little as possible, ideally not at all.

So, without knowing all the details, here is what your objects could look like:

```java
public class Student {
    public boolean isBetterAtMathThan(Student other) {
        ...
    }
}

public class Students { // or StudentRepository
    public Student getBestStudentAtMath() {
        return students.stream().max(toComparator(Student::isBetterAtMathThan)).get();
    }
}
```

Or, if you really want to generalize over a couple of different comparable skills, then you still can do that without exposing the data from Students:

```java
public class Students {
    public Student getBestStudentAt(Comparator<Student> skillComparator) {
        return students.stream().max(skillComparator).get();
    }
}
```

The point is, the `Student` should not expose data, but offer operations, or create other objects that can *do* stuff. Similarly, `Students` (the Service in your code) should not expose a list of students, instead it should provide methods to actually *do* stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,This works if there is only Math (isBetterAtMathThan). , I can hide my data or pass in only the required info.  The reason going for Factory is, There can be another Scorer, which might depend upon different set of data.

Comment: But, I agree with your points. But Can you address this with different implementations like the Factory I posted !!

Comment: I would have to know what your goal/requirement is. Normally, all the "scoring" should be done in the `Student`, since the data is there. Other classes then can select which scoring is needed. If you really want this to be 'pluggable' (only do this if you really need it), then you would have to create some abstraction that does not require getting data from `Student`. It might be supplied during construction of the 'scorer' perhaps.

Comment: >> It might be supplied during construction of the 'scorer' perhaps
But, We have multiple implementation of scorer, Each scorer may have different data dependencies.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to define some uniform interface for the scorers that makes sense? My point was, that instead of the scorers directly get()ing stuff from `Student`, maybe the `Student` could push "data" into the scorers.

Comment: If we can't define that uniform interface between different scorers. How about both Student and Scorers to get their stuff from some other class ?

Comment: That's ok from the perspective of OO as long as they don't have direct access to internal data of that class.

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems with doing that. It is a common practice, known as the [Strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).

Using injection like that is a very useful technique for decoupling logic, allowing unit testing of each component, by supplying mock objects.

Comment: A strategy pattern does the references in one direction. Here, We are doing circular way !!